# Calculating distance between addresses in Excel/Libreoffice?

Tags: microsoft-excel, libreoffice, google-maps

I have a spreadsheet of addresses, and I need to sort by their distance to a reference address. Currently, I have to manually copy and paste each address into Google Maps and request driving directions, but this is tedious. Is there any way to automate this via a formula or plugin?

I'm using Libreoffice on Ubuntu.

Comment: You should look at the [Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix), though you will need to [subscribe](https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/) as a developer. You should be able to use scripting to call the API.

Comment: @AFH, I know how to query Google's APIs to calculate the distance. I'm asking how to do this from inside Libreoffice.

Comment: And you can't do this from scripting? Searching for "libreoffice scripting call google api" gives plenty of script samples among the results.